# Purchased an entire season of a show, but newest episodes are requesting payment of $2.99

Tags: itunes, appletv, television

We purchased 'How I met your mother, Season 8' through iTunes.

and this worked well for Episodes 1-14, however episodes 15 and 16 are not viewable, and are requesting to be purchased for $2.99/ea.

What's the best way to proceed?  The situation is the same both through iTunes and our AppleTVs.

Answer (score 1):

Submit a Help request thru the iTunes store.  This happened to me for Archer Season 4, Episode 4.  Took about 3-4 days, and then I finally got the email saying it was ready for me to download.  Didn't happen to any of the other shows I buy.

Not sure if the Help ticket helped, but it didn't hurt...